# AppStoreConnect version coding for test and release

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have an app I developed in Xcode for Apple devices, and I have the following question I'm not sure how to deal with.

I have a server side to my app, and for testing I use a development URL, which has dummy data. When releasing, I connect to the live URL, which is connected to the live data.

Now, sometimes I make a build with the development URL that I want to put into [TestFlight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestFlight) for the users to test, but I want to make sure that its clear on the app store connect, that this is a build connected to the development URL. I don't want in the future to publish this build by mistake. So I tried in the version to put **2.0.2-DEV**, but when sending to the App Store, Xcode gave me an error:

> The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value.

And this is because the version code has to be number.number.numnber without any text.

I also tried to do it, that the builds connected to the development URL, will be coded from 9.0.0, etc. However, once I did this, when I released new versions with the live URL, for example. 2.0.1, the users were not notified, since this number is before 9.0.0

I hope it’s clear what I am trying to say,

So how can I label a build to be using the dev development URL, so it will be clear on the app store connect that it’s not a live build?

Answer (score 0):

You can *not* release a development and production to TestFlight. TestFlight is only for production.

But you can:

- Always release the app using *Phased release*, so you can halt the rollout quickly if you released the wrong version.
- You can use only odd numbers for development and even numbers for production